# Checkbox.checked false in page_load

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, webforms

I'm obviously not completely clear on how websites work.

`(Using vb.net, visual studio, web forms)`
But here goes:

1. Is it normal that after every postback-page_load, another page_load always happens (which is NOT a postback)? Or is this something weird of the website I'm currently adapting?
2. Why is the checkbox.checked-property always false in the page_load, although it's checked when the page is loaded?

Actual problem: I have a page with a gridview, bound to a dataset. On page_load I dynamically add a few extra columns depending on certain conditions. (I'm adding them only if page_load is not a postback.)

Now, I have added an `asp:checkbox`. If it's checked, I want the page to reload and add the columns but in a slightly different way (so that it's editable). I tried to check the checkbox.checked-property on page_load, but this is what happens: first, I get a postback-page_load, where the checked-property is true (as I would expect). However, immediately after that I get a `normal` page_load where the check-property is false- although after the page is loaded, the checkbox IS checked.

Since I'm adding the extra columns on `normal` page_load, and then `checked` is always false, the columns are always added the regular way...

Maybe I shouldn't be adding the columns in `normal` page_load but in postback- or in both. But as it is, the adding of the columns is working, and in this case, if I'd add them in postback too it wouldn't make a difference because it will always be followed by a `normal` page_load in which the checked-property is false.

What am I missing??

Comment: I don't think Page_Load should be firing twice, do you have any controls that update the page themselves?
 
Also, you should try enclosing your gridview binding in a   `if(!IsPostBack)` statement (I'm not sure of the VB equivalent, sorry!). You could also try using the AutoPostback function of the Checkbox and use the OnCheckedChanged event. You could rebind your gridview with the extra columns here.

Comment: Are you adding the extra columns to the gridview - or the dataset? I find if I want, for example, row headings in a grid, or an extra column in certain circumstances, I modify the dataset and then bind the grid. If you modify the grid, it seems to lose the modifications when you postback and you have to recreate them.

Comment: I add them to the grid, not the dataset. It doesn't really matter I think in this case, because the regular page_load always follows the postback which "resets" the grid..

Comment: No, PageLoad always takes place before whatever you are calling when you postback.

Comment: As said in (1), I'm looking at a website that when I click a button I get a page_load-event with postback=true, but shortly after that a page_load with postback=false. Question: is this normal? I guess it isn't and it's something that's wrong with this website...

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure whether `EnableViewState` property is set to TRUE which is by default.

The state of the server controls is maintained in ViewState so the problem would occur only if this property is set to FALSE.

And you should do your Data binding with if (NOT IsPostBack)

```
            Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
            Try
                If Not IsPostBack Then
                    GetAllContentAnnouncement()
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
```